# mounting devices not allow binaries

Tags: linux, unix

what command will mount device /device/sdal to the mount point /mnt/usb with a filesystem type of ext 3 and not allow binaries executed from the device

Answer (score 2):

mount -t ext3 -o noexec /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb

Answer (score 1):

That should do it:

```
mount -t ext3 /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb -o noexec
```

Answer (score 1):

The `noexec` option should do this. If you're using the `user` option, `noexec` is implied.

http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount